# Where do I store the values passed to a macro method in a Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

In my app, I can calculate `Result`s for a measurement. The result model uses Single Table Inheritance to define different result types, each of which implements a `calculate` method. Now, I need to calculate some results before others. Example:

```
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :measurement

  def calculate
    raise "#calculate is abstract. Implement this method in one of the subclasses."
  end

  def self.depends_on(args)
    # what to do here?
  end

end
```

One subclass could look like:

```
# The total duration in milliseconds
class TotalDuration < Result

  depends_on :EventList # calculate the EventList result first

  def calculate
    # how do I find out what I depend on?
    # only then do the actual calculation
  end

end
```

As you can see, I've already included a `depends_on` class method, with which I'd like to express that the `TotalDuration` result needs the `EventList` result calculated before.

But how do I access the information at runtime, e.g. when I'm inside `calculate`? There for example I could calculate the dependency first, then continue.

I would assume that using class level attributes (e.g., `@@depends_on`) are not considered good style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
def self.depends_on(*args)
  define_method("calculate_dependencies") do
    args.each do |arg|
      measurement.results.where(type: arg.to_s).each { |result| result.calculate unless result.value }
    end
  end
end
```

This way, I only have to call

```
def calculate
  calculate_dependencies
  # other stuff
end
```

in my child models. I could even go as far as defining a new method with the name of the dependent result:

```
define_method("#{arg.to_s.underscore}") do
  results = measurement.results.where(type: arg.to_s).limit(1)
  result = results.first if results.any?
  result.calculate if result.value.nil?
  result
end
```

That way, I could do:

```
depends_on :EventList

def calculate
  # no need for calculate_dependencies
  event_list  # <= this is the result I depend on, already calculated
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a join model which allows any particular instance of `Result` to `have_many` dependent results.

Then in your calculate method for a result with dependencies you first ask for the calculations from the dependent results before continuing with your own calculation.

Through natural recursion, if any of those dependent results had further dependencies ... this would naturally filter up the chain.

Comment: Hm, that sounds like a nice alternative, although it's a little tangential to the specific issue I have here, assuming I wanted to do this with this macro-style `depends_on :something` approach. If I created a join model, how would I define the association *in code*, in the model itself, and not at runtime or through database seeds?

Comment: Well, I guess you could go down the route of concerns, which would allow you to effectively 'mixin' the associations, however that really just moves the code to another file. I can see what you're trying to achieve, but I wonder whether you're overengineering a solution for the sake of it, rather than through necessity?

Comment: The thing is... in this application, there will be quite a few result types, and they have to be manageable (implementable) by people who *are* able to program, but not Rails experts. So they should just touch the subclasses, implement `calculate` and be done with it.

Comment: I think I have a solution; posted it as an answer. Still +1 for your suggestion, much appreciated.